# Find differences in two arrays with duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I have two arrays
for example

```
a1 = ["1","2","7","7"];
a2 = ["1","2","7"];
```

I have to write function in plain javascript to find diferrences . I do not have any streams, list etc..

My code is

```
lastproducts = new List();
   for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {

  if (a2.indexOf(a1[i]) == -1) {
    lastproducts.insertIntoList(lastproducts.listLength,a1[i])}
    }
    return lastproducts;
}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't know the difference.
I'd like you to spot a duplicate, and return in this case "7" ;

Can You help me ?
Thank You

Comment: Of course javascript my bad

Comment: what is your expected output from those 2 inputs? could you also include a few more examples?